# Sending email from flutter app background is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get my flutter app to send emails as a background process. I have been following the official documentation for the mailer package and the YouTube video they suggest to follow as well.

What I am trying to do is allow the current logged in user to add other users by filling out a user profile page. When they click on the "Save" button an account is setup in Firebase using the Google email and password authentication. This works fine. The new account has a default password so I want to send an email to the new user notifying them that they have an account for the app and that they need to create a new password.

Next step, after the account has been created I want to create the email and send it as part of a background process.

I am having trouble getting the code to work.

Here is what I have so far. This is the code for the Save button:

```
RoundedButton(
                  title: 'Save',
                  colour: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      if (widget.isNewUser!) {
                        // Add new user account to Cloud Firestore
                        try {
                          UserCredential result =
                              await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: email, password: "NewPassword");

                          if (result.user != null) {
                            final User user = result.user!;
                            newUser.userId = user.uid;

                            ref.read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier).saveUser(
                                  ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider),
                                  newUser,
                                );

                            // Send email to new user with password and reset link
                            sendNewUserEmail();
                          }
                        } catch (error) {
                          var e = error as FirebaseAuthException;
                          print(e.message!);
                        }

                        // Send email to new user with password.

                      } else {
                        ref.read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier).saveUser(
                              ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider),
                              ref.read(usersNotifierProvider),
                            );
                      }

                      if (isChecked) {
                        ref
                            .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateAddCompany(false);
                        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const CompanyScreen()));
                      } else {
                        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const MainScreen()));
                      }

                      ref.read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier).saveFcmToken(
                          ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId!,
                          '${ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).fName} ${ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).lName!}');

                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      // todo: add better error handling
                      //print(e);
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

Here is the code that I need to add to the onPressed function:

```
 Future sendNewUserEmail() async {
    final googleUser = await GoogleAuthApi.signIn();
    final accessToken = '';

    final smtpServer = gmailSaslXoauth2('myemail@gmail.com', accessToken);
    final message = Message()
      ..from = const Address("myemail@gmail.com", "Deal Diligence")
      ..recipients = ['newUser@gmail.com']
      ..subject = "Welcome to Deal Diligence"
      ..text = "Welcome to Deal Diligence. Your password is NewPassword";

    try {
      await send(message, smtpServer);

    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

class GoogleAuthApi() {  <<<  ERROR HERE
  Static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    if (await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn) {
      return _googelSignIn.CurrentUser;
    } else {
      return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting an error on the class GoogleAuthApi saying

```
A class declaration must have a body, even if it is empty.
Try adding an empty body.
```

Why can I not do this?

Is there a good example of how to do this that actually works?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uhmm, you're using a "Pythonic" style of class declaration. Class declarations in `Dart` follow C++ like syntax, So replace:

```
class GoogleAuthApi() { 
  Static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    if (await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn) {
      return _googelSignIn.CurrentUser;
    } else {
      return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    }
  }
}
```

with:

```
class GoogleAuthApi{ 
  Static final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Static Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    if (await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn) {
      return _googelSignIn.CurrentUser;
    } else {
      return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    }
  }
}
```

take a look at [docs](https://dart.dev/language/classes)